# Get Distribution Group Members

Tags: c#, exchangewebservices

I'm simply trying to get a list of users/email addresses that are members of a given Exchange Distribution Group.

It's a Mail Universal Distribution Group, and it does have members. (I double checked)

Per the MSDN examples I've found, this is the code I am using.

I always get back an exception of "No results found". Not a 'normal" message saying it found nothing, an actual exception.

_service is my Exchange Service (which is working properly).
It errors out on the ExpandGroup line.

```
    try
    {
        // Return the expanded group.

        Microsoft.Exchange.WebServices.Data.ExpandGroupResults myGroupMembers = _service.ExpandGroup(distributionListMember).;

        // Display the group members.
        foreach (Microsoft.Exchange.WebServices.Data.EmailAddress address in myGroupMembers.Members)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Email Address: {0}", address);
            //listBox1.Items.Add(address.Address);
        }
    }
    catch (Microsoft.Exchange.WebServices.Data.ServiceResponseException ex)
    {
        MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
    }
    catch (Exception)
    {

        MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
    }
```

Is there something I'm missing? This group is not a Dynamic Distribution Group nor a Mail Universal Security Group. 100% Mail Universal Distribution Group.

Answer (score 0):

This is a known Microsoft Exchange Server 2010 [issue](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/2579671/no-results-returned-when-you-use-the-expandgroup-method-in-ews-to-retr).

> This issue occurs because the ExchangeService.ExpandGroup method that
> EWS uses does not expand the Dynamic Distribution Group when it tries
> to determine the list of members.

---

> To resolve this issue, install the following update rollup:
>
> [2608646](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/2608646/description-of-update-rollup-6-for-exchange-server-2010-service-pack-1) Description of Update Rollup 6 for Exchange Server 2010 Service Pack 1

*Note*: There is a full stop at the end of this line which I think shouldn't be there.

```
_service.ExpandGroup(distributionListMember).;
```